# Syntax error in the below update command

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

Could someone please tell me where I am going with the syntax in this update command?

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE VolunteerDetails" & "SET FirstName=" & Me.frst_Name_txt & ", LastName='" & Me.lst_Name_txt & "'" & " WHERE VolsID=" & Me.vol_ID_txt
```

Thanks!

I have tried it a new way, to make it simpler....but is still giving me a syntax error.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE VolunteerDetails SET FirstName=Me.frst_Name_txt, LastName=Me.lst_Name_txt, WHERE VolsID=Me.vol_ID_txt"
```

Comment: You seem to miss a space after "UPDATE VolunteerDetails "

Comment: Well your updated version isn't actually using values from your form at all. You should look into parameterized SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Your SQL will look something like:

```
UPDATE VolunteerDetailsSET FirstName=Foo, LastName='Bar' WHERE VolsID=10
```

Three problems with this:

- You have no space between `VolunteerDetails` and `SET`
- You have no apostrophes around the first name to quote it
- You shouldn't be including the values directly in your SQL at all (as you have a SQL injection vulnerability)

It's not clear what language you're using (VB? just straight Access forms?) but you should definitely use parameterized SQL. If you can give us more data about your environment, we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. For the record I am using access built in querying tool, so whatever language that runs off

Comment: It is VB btw, I just looked it up